# Calculating the dimensions of a rendered string of text (before rendering it)

Tags: java, string, canvas, paint

I want to align a String drawn by a **canvas** perfectly in the middle.  So if I have code like so

```
Paint p = new Paint();
Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();

String centered_text = "Hello World";
```

and then set my Paint **style** and **size**

```
p.setTextSize(35);
p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
```

Now to draw my String in the middle I would do

```
c.drawText(centered_text, c.getWidth()/2, c.getHeight()/2, p);
```

But this wouldn't actually center my text, it would put the top left corner in the center.  To center it I would need to know the Strings litteral width and height in pixels not characters.

```
int string_width = centered_text.getWidth(); //String.getWidth() is not a real methode
int string_height = centered_text.getHeight(); //String.getHeight() is not a real methode

c.drawText(centered_text, (c.getWidth()/2)-(string_width/2), (c.getHeight()/2)-(string_height/2), p);
```

This would center the text but `String.getWidth()` and `String.getHeight()` are not real methodes.  So my idea is to use the **size** of the **text** and the **size** of the **String** to find the **width** and the **height**.  So something along te lines of:

```
int string_width = centered_text.length()*p.getTextSize();
int string_height = p.getTextSize();
```

But I feel like this is wrong because different chars are different sizes... anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Not an answer but: yes, if you're not using monospaced fonts, different characters will have different widths. Furthermore, if the rendering is advanced enough, it may introduce kerning (i.e. variable space between the fonts). Finally, you probably don't want to vertically align to the middle of the tallest letter and the baseline, but from the X-Height of the font to the baseline.

Comment: What library are you using? In SWT you've got `getStringExtent(String). Check [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratesFontMetricsandextents.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're in Java Swing, what you want is [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html).

```
new FontMetrics(canvas.getFont()).getStringBounds(someString, canvas.getGraphics());
```

will return a Rectangle2D with the size of your string in it.